# Removing leading zeros from alphanumeric cells in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to remove leading zeros from ID numbers that are alphanumeric and very random. I've tried other methods found here but they will work for 90% of the IDs but totally delete others. I have a working formula for basic Excel that removes the zeros and I'm trying to work it into VBA code. I keep receiving error 1004 - application defined or object defined error on the line with the formula in it.

```
    range("E2").select
    activecell.formula="=right(D2,len(D2)-find(left(substitute(D2,'0',''),1),D2)+1)"
```

My understanding of activecell.formula is that it inserts this formula exactly inside the cell so since the formula works (with ' replaced with " inside the substitute function) I can't figure out why I am getting this error. Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to use `""` instead of `'`: `range("E2").formula="=right(D2,len(D2)-find(left(substitute(D2,""0"",""""),1),D2)+1)"`

Comment: vba: `Range("E2").Value = Mid(Range("D2"), InStr(Range("d2"), Left(Replace(Range("d2"), "0", ""), 1)))`

Comment: Is `Replace(Range("d2"), "0", "")` not sufficient?

Comment: @ScottCraner that was the fix I was missing, it works now. Thank you!